# Physics Material 2D Not Working When Object Rotating Around Player

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I am trying to make a clone of florr.io (I'm not getting sued I know what I'm doing), assuming you don't know what that is, it is a game with petals rotating around you. I'm using a parent object holding an object with a greater x position to make the child object rotate around the player. The problem is that when I put a physics material on the Rigidbody or the collider on the child object, the mob, which uses impulses to move with a 5 seconds cooldown, doesn't bounce off the object when it is getting pushed by it, but it does when it impulses to the side of the object. Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you configured this physics material?

Comment: Yes, the bounciness is 1.5